# Substituting nth occurrence of a string in a for loop, in a file, with another string using sed

Tags: bash, sed

I am trying to replace the (j+1)th occurrence of "Nb " with Nbu in my file that looks like this:

```
Nb  Nbc blahblahblah
Nb  blablablaNbblabla
Cd  Nb
and many lines that follow
```

where j is a variable in a for loop.

What I want to get is something like this. For example, when j=1:

```
Nb  Nbc blahblahblah
Nbu blablablaNbblabla
Cd  Nb
and many lines that follow
```

The code I have now looks something like the following:

```
for j in $(seq 1 1 4)
do
sed -i ':a;N;$!ba;s/Nb /Nbu/$((j+1))' file
done
```

However, I get a error message:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 21: unknown option to `s'
```

The problem seems to come from the $((j+1)) because when I changed the code to

```
sed -i ':a;N;$!ba;s/Nb /Nbu/2' file
```

I get my desired output for j=1.

What should the syntax be to include the looping j?

Comment: `Nbf` is a typo? Why is it substituted? There is no space after `Nb` in the third line. Why don't you just substitute `Nb ` with `Nbu` every 3rd line? Does the second column also count to the count of `Nb` occurrences or not?

Comment: Nbf is not a typo, there are several occurrences with Nb and some other strings. This is just an example of my full code. In my full code, I only need to change the 3rd occurrence and that's it. The second column also counts for Nb occurrences. I have updated the question to make this clearer.

Comment: So you don't want to substitute `Nb<space>` just `Nb` right? Why do you then `s/Nb /` and not `s/Nb/` ? And why `Nbf`? Where it came from? There was `Nb` in the input file on the 3rd line 2nd column. Does the `blablablaNbblabla` count to the number of `Nb` too?

Comment: I want to substitute Nb<space> with Nbu. Assume Nbf as just a string that happens to have Nb in it; I want to substitute Nb<space> with Nbu exactly because I don't want to change these strings with Nb in them. and for the 3rd line 2nd column, yes there is another Nb there, just assume it as another occurrence.

Comment: The single quotes around the sed script are preventing variable expansion. You are expecting a number, but sed is seeing a '$'. Not a valid flag for s

Comment: Does `Nbc` count to the number of occurences? Why not? Does the file has two columns?

Comment: @drclaw, yes, but changing the single quotes to double quotes will make the first half of the code  sed -i ':a;N;$!ba;s/Nb /Nbu/$((j+1))' file not work.

Comment: So just mix them `sed -i ':a;N;$!ba;s/Nb /Nbu/'"$((j+1))"`

Comment: @KamilCuk Nbc does not count as an occurrence as it is not Nb<space>

Comment: try sed -i ':a;N;$!ba;s/Nb /Nbu/'$((j+1)) file

Comment: @drclaw Thanks a lot, it worked! I didn't know the single quote doesn't have to be placed after everything. Do you mind copying your comment as an answer so it'll be easier for others to read this too? Once again, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The single quotes around the sed script are preventing variable expansion. You are expecting a number, but sed is seeing a '$'. Not a valid flag for s

Break up the quoted section to allow variable expansion

```
 sed -i ':a;N;$!ba;s/Nb /Nbu/'$((j+1)) file
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one using GNU awk and `gensub`:

```
$ awk -v j=1 -v RS="" '{print gensub(/Nb /,"Nbu",j+1)}' file
Nb  Nbc blahblahblah
Nbu blablablaNbblabla
Cd  Nb
and many lines that follow
```

If there are more than one paragraph in the text, `awk -v RS="^$"` is the way.